# gRPC and clean architecture - Where to place proto files

Tags: microservices, grpc, clean-architecture, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I'm using grpc in the asp.net project with clean architecture, where should I put proto files and grpc services which layer, and which folder

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When taking Clean Architecture (from Uncle Bob) very strict gRPC should be considered as a "framework" (technical detail) and so all code depending on it (including proto files) should be outside the domain/application layer and in the outer most layer.